# Shortcut for character with key "alt" suddenly not working anymore in VIM (e.g."#" obtained with "alt + 3"): In quits insert mode instead

Tags: vim, character, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

I'm using VIM as text editor for a few weeks now.

I could write character dependent on hitting key <kbd>alt</kbd> without problem

Ex:

- <kbd>alt-3</kbd> gave the the character "#"
- <kbd>alt-5</kbd> gave the the character "["
- <kbd>alt-6</kbd> gave the the character "]"

But suddenly it changed and now when hit those shortcuts, it does not write the corresponding character and quits insert mode instead

When I'm outside Vim those shorcuts work fine

Did I change something by mistake? What should I do to fix the problem? Should I change the `~/vimrc` file